# CentOSにDocker Desktopをインストール出来ない

Tags: linux, docker, centos

Docker DesktopをCentOS7にインストールしようと、[公式の手順](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/fedora/)を基に実行しましたが、うまくインストール出来ず、以下のエラーが表示されました。どうすればいいでしょうか？

```
Docker CE Stable - x86_64                       0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
repo 'docker-ce-stable' のキャッシュの同期に失敗しました、この repo を無視します。
メタデータの期限切れの最終確認: 19:11:23 時間前の 2022年09月20日 15時19分05秒 に実施しました。
エラー: 
 問題: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.18)(64bit) needed by docker-desktop-4.12.0-85629.x86_64
  - nothing provides pass needed by docker-desktop-4.12.0-85629.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Desktop for Linux が現時点でサポートしているのは Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora のみであり、**CentOS は含まれていません**。

[Install Docker Desktop on Linux](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/)

あなたが参照しているドキュメントは Fedora 向けの手順ですが、CentOS と Fedora では OS の核となる Kernel や glibc のバージョンが大きく異なるため、CentOS で Fedora 向けのパッケージをそのまま使うことは出来ません。( [CentOS 向けの導入手順はこちら](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/) )

あなたが実行したコマンドの実行結果では docker-desktop パッケージの動作に **glibc-2.18** を要求されていますが、CentOS 7 では **glibc-2.17** までしかサポートしていません。

[glibc-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm | CentOS 7](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/glibc-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。お陰様で、なぜうまく行かないのかを理解することが出来ました。一方で、docker desktopを使用せずに、doockerのメモリ制限（初期2GB）を任意のメモリサイズに変更するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？
https://techtechmedia.com/docker-trouble-solution/#:~:text=%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83-,%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AF%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B,%E3%81%AB%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82

Comment: インストールできないとは別の話なので、新しい質問として投稿してみてください。